# What is a "secular equation"?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Golub mentioned "secular equation" in his Matrix Computation and [a slide](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/harrachov/slides/Golub.pdf). However I still don't get its definition. How is a secular equation defined? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A secular equation is another name for the characteristic equation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Secular_equation

The reason it is called "secular" is because it was first used in calculations relating the planetary motion:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_phenomena

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_variation

The etymological root of "secular" is "*saeculum*," meaning "of an age."

Comment: Why it is called secular equation? Is there also a sacred equation?

Comment: @Popopo See my edits above.

Comment: @steveO:  secular here means one direction of change with time, as opposed to periodic.  If you have $f(t)=at+b \sin t$, the $at$ is the secular part and the $b \sin t$ is the periodic part.

Comment: It's helpful. Thank you.

Comment: An attempt to clarify "secular" vs. "sacred": As far as I know, "saeculum" can mean either "age" or "world".  The former meaning leads to secular equations, the latter leads to non-sacred things.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thank you.  Can you provide a link that expands upon your answer?  It is difficult searching online for the term in the context you laid out.