# How to solve numerically the secular equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, newton-raphson

I need to solve numerically the secular equation

$$f(t) = 1 + \rho \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{z_i^2}{d_i-t}$$

where $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{d_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are known. I implemented an algorithm that alternates between the bisection method and Newton method (see [here](https://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/numerical_recipes.pdf), bottom of page 460). The algorithm converges, but it takes many iterations to do so.

How is the secular equation solved numerically nowadays? I know this is done in variations of [divide and conquer algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm) for eigenvalues.

Comment: See lecture 30 of the fantastic book "Numerical Linear Algebra" by L. Trefethen and D. Bau (SIAM, 1997)

Comment: For those who are not aware, 'secular equation' = 'characteristic polynomial'. A full explanation can be found in [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335795/what-is-a-secular-equation).

Comment: Have you seen [Li's technical report](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1994/5882.html) already (also [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn89.pdf))?

Answer (score 2):

Written as 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i\, z_i}{\alpha_i- \theta}=1-q$$ this is an equation we worked extensively in my research group because of its importance in chemical process simulation (in a single simulation, we have to solve it *zillions* of times). Our most recnt work was puplished in 2014 (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135414003019)) where we propose extremely good estimates of the solution; typically, we need only between $3$ and $5$ iterations because of the convex transformations we proposed.

On this site, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078167/efficient-algorithm-for-solving-equation-sum-n-a-n-x-x-n-1/3079024#3079024).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody. I eventually implemented [this](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn89.pdf) paper and performance increased dramatically, from ~15 iterations per root to less than 4.