# What is the method to solve this type of unknown equation

Tags: polynomials

I have an equation of the format below
$$
-\frac{1}{\alpha} = \sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{v_r^2}{\omega_r^2-\Omega}
$$
([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XgH2.png))

For $m=5$ the right hand side becomes
$$\frac{v_1^2}{\omega_1^2-\Omega} + \frac{v_2^2}{\omega_2^2-\Omega} + \frac{v_3^2}{\omega_3^2-\Omega} + \frac{v_4^2}{\omega_4^2-\Omega} + \frac{v_5^2}{ω_5^2-\Omega}.
$$
([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAMJ8.png))

$v_r$ and $\omega$ are known scalar values.

The only unknown variable is $\Omega$.

The equation after substituting variables will look like this (these aren’t exact values of $v$, $\alpha$ and $\omega_r$):

$$
-\frac{1}{10} = \frac{1.66}{1-\Omega} + \frac{2}{2.45-\Omega} + \frac{3.8}{3-\Omega} + \frac{4}{4.56-\Omega} + \frac{5}{5-\Omega}
$$
([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPJ2H.png))

What type of equation is this?

What is the best approach to solve this problem regardless of what the value of $m$ is?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I formatted the mathematics for you. If you click Edit then you can see how it was done.

Comment: Where does the equation come from?

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$. When $n \ge 5$, it is not solvable with algebraic methods. Your best course of action is solving it numerically. Assume $\omega_k^2 < \omega_{k+1}^2$ for $1 \le k < n$ and all $v_\ell^2 > 0$, there are $n-1$ roots in the interval $(\omega^2_k,\omega_{k+1}^2)$ for $1 \le k < n$. Once you get those $n-1$ roots, the last root can be found by apply Vieta's formula to the corresponding polynomial.

Comment: This is called a secular equation ; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3437726) for hints about numerical methods

Comment: Thanks so much for the formatting @md2perpe, I will check how that works

Comment: @md2perpe The equation is part of structure's state analysis problem and it's a step in the process.

Comment: @hardmath I am not sure there is a specific relationship between m and Ω, except that I think it will affect the number of Ω that satisfy the equation

Comment: Yes you got that right @hardmath, that what I meant

Answer (score 2):

This equation asks for the roots of a rational function in unknown variable $\Omega$:

$$ -\frac{1}{\alpha} = \sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{v_r^2}{\omega_r^2-\Omega} $$

where we assume for the sake of definiteness that $\alpha \gt 0$, and also that the $v_r \gt 0$ and $\omega_r$ are distinct and nonnegative (otherwise rewriting the equation will assure this):

$$ 0 \le \omega_1 \lt \omega_2 \lt \ldots \lt \omega_m $$

With basic algebra it can be converted to a polynomial equation of degree $m$, so there are at most $m$ roots.  In fact we can deduce the locations (intervals) of exactly $m$ real roots from the *rational* form of the equation.

The right hand side expression has discontinuities (simple poles) at the arguments $\Omega = \omega_r^2$ where each respective term goes from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ as $\Omega$ increases past that singularity.

Note that for $\Omega < \omega_1^2$ all the terms on the right hand side are strictly positive, while the left hand side is strictly negative.  Therefore there are no solutions of the equation in the interval $(-\infty,\omega_1^2)$.

At the other extreme, as $\Omega \to +\infty$ the right hand side tends to zero from below because when $\Omega \gt \omega_m^2$ all the terms there are negative (but grow increasingly tiny).  On the other hand, as $\Omega$ approaches $\omega_m^2$ from above, the right hand side as a whole approaches $-\infty$.  Therefore, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, the interval $(\omega_m^2,+\infty)$ contains a root, and because the expression on the right hand side is (strictly) monotone increasing there (as negative values), that root is unique in that interval.

Similarly each of the intervals $(\omega_r^2,\omega_{r+1}^2)$ between "fence posts" $\omega_r, 1 \le r \lt m$ will contain a root because the right hand side expression continuously swings from arbitrarily large negative values just above $\omega_r$ to arbitrarily large positive values just below $\omega_{r+1}$.

This accounts for the locations of the maximum possible number of roots, at least in the case that (as assumed above) $\alpha \gt 0$ (so that the left hand side of the equation is negative).  If we instead ask for $\alpha \lt 0$, this would remove the root from $(\omega_m^2,+\infty)$ and introduce a new root in $(-\infty,\omega_1^2)$.

Here is a (Desmos prepared) graph that illustrates the rational curve crossing the line $y=-0.1$ corresponding to the example at the end of the Question:

[image: secular equation from Question]

In any case once the roots are suitably isolated in this fashion, it is pretty easy to obtain accurate numerical approximations.  Robust methods like [bisection and regula falsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Bracketing_methods) can sharpen the initial approximations to a region where Newton's method etc. begin rapid convergence as necessary.